# SQL-Server: Why do we use FILE = 1 in scripts for restoring a database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, backup, restore

Recently when I came across the script for restoring a database, I got a doubt on why we have to use "***FILE = 1***"? Can't we restore a database without that statement!? Basically, what it is used for?

Answer (score 33):

You are allowed to save more than one backup in a backup file (i.e. device). The `FILE` clause lets you access a particular backup operation when there are multiple to choose from within the `.bak` file.

For more information on the various options of the [RESTORE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-transact-sql) command, please see the following Microsoft documentation for [RESTORE Arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-arguments-transact-sql).

If you look under the **Backup Set Options** section (within the **Syntax** description), you will find:

> FILE ={ *backup_set_file_number* | @*backup_set_file_number* }
>
> Identifies the backup set to be restored. For example, a *backup_set_file_number* of **1** indicates the first backup set on the backup medium and a *backup_set_file_number* of **2** indicates the second backup set. You can obtain the *backup_set_file_number* of a backup set by using the RESTORE HEADERONLY statement.
>
> When not specified, the default is 1, except for RESTORE HEADERONLY in which case all backup sets in the media set are processed. For more information, see "Specifying a Backup Set," later in this topic.
>
> **Important**
> This FILE option is unrelated to the FILE option for specifying a database file, FILE = { *logical_file_name_in_backup* | @*logical_file_name_in_backup_var* }.

Yes, you should be able to restore without the `FILE = 1` as `1` is the default anyway. And, if you only ever have a single backup-set in a backup file, then it shouldn't pose a problem.

An example to help illustrate when you would use the `FILE` option is the following, which is [Example B](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-transact-sql#restoring_full_n_differential_db_backups) from the `RESTORE` command documentation page (linked above). It shows doing two restores from a single backup file: the first `RESTORE` is the FULL backup, and the second `RESTORE` is the DIFFerential backup.

```sql
RESTORE DATABASE AdventureWorks2012
   FROM DISK = 'Z:\SQLServerBackups\AdventureWorks2012.bak'
   WITH FILE = 6
      NORECOVERY;
RESTORE DATABASE AdventureWorks2012
   FROM DISK = 'Z:\SQLServerBackups\AdventureWorks2012.bak'
   WITH FILE = 9
      RECOVERY;
```

Comment: It's important to note for people that there is nothing magical about 6 & 9, in this example the full backup is indicated as the 6th file in the backup set - but that only pertains to this example. Same for the differential backup file, it's the 9th in the set in this example. Specifying 6 or 9 is only mentioning which file in the set to use. If you have only one file in your backup set, you must not specify a number, or specify 1 only